# How do I make an array add up?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I want to add an array add up.

Let's say there's an array of [7, 1, 21, 70]

On a an array index of 0, it would just be 7. On an array index of 1, I want it to be 7 + 1 (8). Array index 2, 7 + 1 + 21 (29). Array index 3 7 + 1 + 21 + 70 (99).

This is my current code:

```
var pot = {
  'id': 1,
  'name': ['stalin', 'hitler', 'mao', 'kim jong-il'],
  'amount': [50, 10, 150, 500],
  'percentages': new Array()
}

var random = Math.random()*100;
var random = String(random).split(".")[0];
console.log(random);

function potTotal(amounts) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var key in amounts) {
    sum += pot['amount'][key];
  }
  return sum;
}

function potPercentage(total, amounts) {
  for (var key in amounts) {
    var percentage = amounts[key] / total * 100;
    var percentage = String(percentage).split(".")[0];
    var percentage = Number(percentage);
    pot['percentages'].push(percentage);
  }
}

potPercentage(potTotal(pot['amount']), pot['amount']);

function ranging(total, percentages) {
  console.log(percentages);
  for(var i = 0; percentages < i; i++) {
    console.log(percentages[i]);
  }
}
//[7, 1, 21, 70]
ranging(random, pot['percentages']);

for (var key in pot['percentages']) {
  console.log(key);
  console.log(pot['percentages'][key]);
}
```

The results of which return:

```
69
[ 7, 1, 21, 70 ]
0
7
1
1
2
21
3
70
```

Comment: Hi! Please reduce the code in your question to a [mcve] (note the "minimal") demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are looking for `prefix sum` method, try the following:

```js
var arr = [7, 1, 21, 70]; 
 for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] += arr[i-1];
 }
 
 console.log(arr);
```

For Reference : [Prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum)

Comment: @Techius Happy to help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` is the function defined to do this kind tasks.

```js
const arr = [7, 1, 21, 70].reduce((acc, el, i) => [...acc, (acc[i-1] || 0) + el], []);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `forEach()` will do for you:

```js
var arr = [7, 1, 21, 70];
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  if(index - 1 > -1){
    arr[index] += arr[index-1];
  }
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate with a for loop and add the previous item

```
let items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

for (let i = 1; i < items.length; i++)
    items[i] = items[i] + items[i-1];
```

Comment: Thanks dude -- appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I like this as this is so easy to read and does not mutate the original array.

Mapping over an array gives you access to each item in that array one by one (just like a foreach loop) but it also creates a new array containing the return value from the callback.

```js
function addConsecutives(nums) {
   let sum = 0;

   return nums.map(num => sum += num)
}

console.log(addConsecutives([7, 1, 21, 70]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method on the array so that you don't bother managing index while doing the computation and also `reduce` will return you **a brand new array**, with the added benefit of not destroying your original array

```js
var originalArray =  [7, 1, 21, 70];

var addUp = (acc, curr, index) => {
  if (index === 0) acc.push(curr);
  else acc.push(acc[index-1] + curr);
  return acc;
}

var computedArray = originalArray.reduce(addUp, []);

console.log(computedArray);
```